# Set the RatingBar star selection color in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the rating bar to set the clicked star to change the color as yellow.

Here below code for declare the rating bar in XML:

```
<RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    />
```

Below code :

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new Rating Bar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                   ratingValue = String.valueOf(rating);
                }
            });
```

Please help me i am new in android

Comment: If my answer is correct ..tick mark it.